# SQL Query on Kronos Database

Tags: sql

Is there a way where I can  optimize the following query to get my results faster. This is essentially pulling data from a View in Kronos Database called VP_TOTALS

```
SELECT PERSONFULLNAME, PERSONNUM, STARTDTM, ENDDTM, LABORACCTNAME FROM VP_TOTALS
WHERE PAYCODENAME='SCP-PPD Sick' OR PAYCODENAME=’PER’ OR PAYCODENAME=’SCK’
AND
startdtm between to_date('01-NOV-19','DD-MON-YY') 
AND to_date('30-NOV-19' ,'DD-MON-YY');
```

Comment: Please don't tag 3 *very* different RDBMS; it will not get more people to view or answer your question it will only have the opposite effect (and cause confusing). I have removed all those tags, please retag the RDBMS you are *really* using and **only** the RDBMS you are using. (This, however, is clearly not SQL Server due to the use of backticks to delimit identify and the `TO_DATE` function usage.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, your query has a logical flaw. `OR`ed conditions should be surrounded with parentheses.

Then: you could use `IN` instead of `OR`. This *might* improve performance.

I also suspect that you want records for the whole month of November, in which case `BETWEEN ... AND to_date('30-NOV-19' ,'DD-MON-YY')` does not do exactly what you want, since it would evict dates between November 30th at 00:00:01 and 23:59:59.

Also, I would recommend using date litterals instead of `TO_DATE()`. This is the proper way to handle date constants.

I would express your query as:

```
SELECT PERSONFULLNAME, PERSONNUM, STARTDTM, ENDDTM, LABORACCTNAME 
FROM VP_TOTALS
WHERE 
    PAYCODENAME IN ('SCP-PPD Sick', 'PER', 'SCK')
    AND STARTDTM >= DATE'2019-11-01' 
    AND STARTDTM < DATE '2019-12-01'
```

For this query, make sure to have an index on `VP_TOTALS(PAYCODENAME, STARTDTM)`.